# Could not update; currently locked

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

I am inserting the data in a table with a background process. When I try to insert the data in the table then I get the following error:

> Could not update; currently locked.

In my case this table (`JobsTemp`) is not using any where in the operation by the another process but other process of the application is using table of same database.

- What is causing this bug?
- Can I check if database is locked or not?

We are trying to insert the data with a WPF application in an MS Access 2003 database. So how to fix this programmatically?

```
private static string dbFile =
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
        + "\\AppData\\LocalAccess.mdb";
private static string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
    + dbFile + ";";
public bool SalesTPJob_Insert_InAccessDB(DataTable DT)
{
    bool flag = true;
    try
    {
        if (DT != null)
        {
            if (DT.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string deleteQuery = "DELETE  FROM JobsTemp";
                DeleteUpdateRecordFromTable(deleteQuery);
                string SQL = "SELECT top 1 * FROM JobsTemp";
                string INSERT = "INSERT INTO " 
                    + "JobsTemp([JobId],[CustomerId],[JobName],[JobAddress],[City]," 
                    + "[State],[Zip],[IsExisting],[Area])"
                    + " VALUES (@JobId,@CustomerId,@JobName,@JobAddress,@City,@State," 
                    + "@Zip,1,@Area)";

                OleDbConnection OleConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString);
                OleDbDataAdapter OleAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, OleConn);

                OleAdp.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand(INSERT);

                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@JobId", OleDbType.VarChar, 
                    1008, "JobId");
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", OleDbType.VarChar, 
                    1008, "CustomerId");
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@JobName", OleDbType.VarChar, 
                    1008, "JobName");
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@JobAddress", OleDbType.VarChar,  
                    1008, "JobAddress");
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@City", OleDbType.VarChar,  
                    1008, "City");
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@State", OleDbType.VarChar,  
                    1008, "State");
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Zip", OleDbType.VarChar,  
                    4000, "Zip");
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Area", OleDbType.VarChar,  
                    1008, "Area");

                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Connection = OleConn;
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Connection.Open();
                int i = OleAdp.Update(DT);
                OleAdp.InsertCommand.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogFile(ex.ToString());
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

JobsTemp is not using in the any other process.

```
 public int DeleteUpdateRecordFromTable(string query)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection OleConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            int i = 0;
            try
            {
                OleConn.Open();
                OleDbCommand ac = new OleDbCommand(query, OleConn);
                i = ac.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OleConn.Close();
                LogFile(ex.ToString());
            }
            return i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which db you are using .??

Comment: @arifhussainshigri : despite the wrong tag - I assume MS-Access, especially as google comes up with lots of answers for this specific error message : https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/918578

Comment: this is not wrong tag. We are using in the wpf.

Comment: @RajGupta: the access tag says "DO NOT USE this tag for Microsoft Access, use [ms-access] instead. In computer security, general access control includes identification, authorization, authentication, access approval, and audit."

Comment: Changed the tag...

Comment: By this link we are not getting exact solution. support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/918578 . We are trying to insert the data by wpf application in the access 2003 data base. So how to fix this programmatically?

Comment: where is the code? Your try??

Comment: We have added code Please check?

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet dollars to doughnuts that `DeleteUpdateRecordFromTable` is leaving a lock on the table.

The `select` should be fine as it's not changing anything (and depending on whether your database is set up with Optimistic locking or not). However, the `insert` is probably choking on a lock from the `delete`.

For checking whether the table is locked before the doing the insert, you'd probably have to use `oledbTransaction` and setup proper transactions for the `delete` and `insert`; and then handle issues in try/catches as required.

Comment: I have added code of DeleteUpdateRecordFromTable method. Here we are using 'using' keyword. So it's not create ant problem.

Comment: You never close the OleConn in normal execution. You do in the exception, and it SHOULD when OleConn gets garbage collected. However, you have no way of knowing when that is going to happen. So I would (out of habit) explicitly close it when I'm done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the issue recently and I think the problem is that you are not closing the connection after executing the query, as @BIBD mentioned in the comments. You should add `OleConn.Close();` after `i = ac.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Right now it only gets closed when there's an exception.

You should also add a lock around your code, that will make it thread safe. Finally, you should run all your database commands through a single method which will ensure only one command runs at a time and the connection is properly closed every time:

```
public bool ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand command)
{
    if (command == null)
        return false;

    try
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = GetConnection())
        {
            int rowsAffected = 0;

            try
            {
                lock (_executeLock)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.Connection = connection;

                    rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery;

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + " in Database.ExecuteNonQuery with '" + command.CommandText + "'");
            }

            return rowsAffected > 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + " in Database.ExecuteNonQuery while opening connection.");
    }
}
```